# Difference between positional vectors is a tensor?

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vectors, inertial-frames

In the introduction to tensors from NASA here: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/documents/Tensors_TM2002211716.pdf

Page 15, it says:

> But suppose that V1 and V2 were position vectors of points P1 and P2
> in K, and that V1* and V2* were position vectors to the same points P1
> and P2 in K*. The vector extending from P1 to P2 must be the same
> vector in both systems. This vector is V2 – V1 in K and V2* – V1* in
> K*.

> Thus we have V2 – V1 = V2* – V1*

> i.e., while the position vector
> itself is not a tensor, the difference between any two position
> vectors is a tensor of rank 1!

I tried a very simple example based on my understanding:

---

In the (i, j) coordinate system:

V1: (0, 1)

V2: (1, 0)

---

In the (j, -i) coordinate system (the first coordinates rotated about the origin 90deg counter clockwise):

V1*: (1, 0)

V2* (0, -1)

---

V1 and V1* both represent the same point, but their coordinate is different due to different basis.

V1 - V2 = (-1, 1)

V1* - V2* = (1, 1)

It looks like the difference between two position vectors is NOT the same.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite nonstandard approach.

Standard approach is to distinguish between coordinates of a point (n-tuple of numbers given by coordinate maps, in this case cartesian) and vectors, that are arrows from one point to another. The moment you say position vector, you already mean arrow from one point to another, the first point being origin of coordinate system.

The vector in mathematical sense is by definition a tensor of rank 1. Standardly, when we say vector, we already mean this mathematical object, so there is no distinction between tensorial vectors and nontensorial vectors. There is just vector, or coordinates of some point in some cartesian chart.

Now to your question:

> It looks like the difference between two position vectors is NOT the same.

They indeed are the same vector, you are just using different basis to write them down. The first coordinate system defines coordinate basis $e_1$ and $e_2$. The first vector is written in this basis:
$$V_1-V_2=-1 e_1+1 e_2$$
Then you changed the coordinate system and thus also the basis $e^*_1=e_2$ and $e^*_2=-e_1$ and in this basis you have written the second vector:
$$V_1^*-V_2^*=1 e_1^*+1 e_2^*$$
If you now go back to original basis, you will get exactly what you want:
$$V_1^*-V_2^*=-1 e_1+1 e_2$$

You confusion is unfortunate consequence of mixing coordinates, vectors and vector components in one huge mess that the article is doing (to be fair, I did not really read the article, maybe I am too harsh). I just think this is terrible way of learning about vectors and tensors. I would suggest grabbing some book written by mathematician, mathematicians are usually perfectly clear on what is what.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now after looking through other sources as well. It's not that the article I read originally is wrong, but the language used could have been a little more precise.